# Strange MySQL IN behavior

Tags: mysql

OK this is not a question 100%.
I got a big headache today with this and just wanted to know if anyone else had this problem.

Let's say we have a table named "products":

```
ID | product_code
4  | 5201279007942_AKYRO
```

If we run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE product_code
IN ( '5201279007942' )
```

Mysql will return 0 rows as expected.

If we run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE product_code
IN ( 5201279007942 )
```

Mysql will return the above row.

So the "IN" query will act as a "LIKE" query.

Is this behavior normal? Am i missing something here?

Comment: In the second case MySQL performs implicit type conversion, so ``5201279007942_AKYRO`` is converted into `5201279007942`.

Comment: I thought so. Just wanted to be sure that this is ok. Had me hiting my head on my wall.

Answer (score 1):

see the output. There is a difference between string ant int

```
SELECT 
    '5201279007942_AKYRO' IN ('5201279007942') AS string_with_string
    , '5201279007942_AKYRO' IN (5201279007942) AS string_with_num
    , CAST( '5201279007942_AKYRO' AS UNSIGNED) IN (5201279007942) AS cast_to_int_with_num;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     '5201279007942_AKYRO' IN ('5201279007942') AS string_with_string
    ->     , '5201279007942_AKYRO' IN (5201279007942) AS string_with_num
    ->     , CAST( '5201279007942_AKYRO' AS UNSIGNED) IN (5201279007942) AS cast_to_int_with_num;
+--------------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| string_with_string | string_with_num | cast_to_int_with_num |
+--------------------+-----------------+----------------------+
|                  0 |               1 |                    1 |
+--------------------+-----------------+----------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Yeap. There is. I didn't know that there will be a type conversion. Thanks!